# Preprocess json with lombok and jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, lombok

I'm using lombok and jackson together. I need to pre-process a json with this structure. By the way, I can't change json structure.

```
[
    {
        "value1": "INC12345",
        "value2": "12345",
        "task": [
            {
                "status": "A",
                "typeOfClass": "Membership"
            },
            {
                "status": "D",
                "reverseEnum": 1,
                "typeOfClass": "Reverse"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What's the problem? Well, I need to process task's list when the request is received to define the type of object of every task with the attribute `typeOfClass` because there I’’m using different type of class, could receive a Membership’s type, a Reverse’s type, etc, and this classes don’t have anything common. This is my java class.

```
@Data
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Incident.IncidentBuilder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "IncidentBuilder", toBuilder = true)
public class Incident {

  @NotNull
  private String value1;

  @NotNull
  private BigInteger value2;

  @NotNull
  private List<Object> task;

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
  public static class IncidentBuilder {
  }

}
```

I don't have problems with others attributes but when I'm debugging I can see that task list is a `LinkedList`, so I need to pre-process that list to create a list with the specific type of objects. I know how to create a custom deserializer with jackson and I'm looking for a similar solution using lombok to avoid lot of code.

I thought that a builder could help me, but I've got lost and couldn't write a good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`, the `List` is a collection of objects which belong to the same `class` type.

As your `Type` element contains which object it belongs to, I assume, there is a top-level parent class that is the parent to all the `type` objects.

So, instead of declaring it as the `List<Object> task`, I recommend you use `List<ParentClass> task`.